# How to write Python pattern programs

Tags: python-3.x

i need help for my syntax,

[image: Screenshot]

i using code:

```
numbers = 10

for number in range(numbers):
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
        print (number)
```

I don't know how to shorten the code.
If i use conditional like:

```
numbers = 10

for number in range(numbers):
    print (number,end="\t")
    if int(str(numbers)[:1]) != 10:
        number += 1
        print (number)
    elif int(str(numbers)[:1] == 10):
        print (number)
```

It only shows:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is not recommended to update the iteration variable inside for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy (though definitely not best!) way is to just loop it twice:

```
numbers = 10
for rowIndex in range(numbers):
    rowString = ''
    for columnIndex in range(numbers): #Same number of points
        #each row is equivalent to the previous row + 1 - use existing iterator
        rowString += str(columnIndex + rowIndex) + '\t'
    print(rowString)
```

By way of explanation of what your code's currently doing:
You're converting *numbers* (i.e. 10) to a string, then taking a substring starting at character zero and ending before character 1. This will always be '1'
You're converting that back to an int (i.e. 1)
You're then comparing that to 10. Since 1 does not equal 10, all you're doing is printing *number + 1* after your first print
Something similar would work if you used range(numbers) instead, but without another loop it's still only going to print one more column

Comment: um, why there's a empty line between every line?

Comment: Because I briefly forgot how the print function works! Removed the newline character now

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
numbers = 10

for number in range(numbers):
    for i in range(numbers):
        print (number,end="\t")
        number += 1
    print('\n',end='')
```

You can add nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

```
numbers = 10
for number in range(numbers):
    print(" ".join([str(index) for index in range(number, numbers + number )]))
```